# How to use KeyValuePattern with individual replacement rules?

Tags: pattern-matching, associations

What's the syntax to use individual replacement rules for key-value patterns?

This returns only the first match:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> /. {KeyValuePattern["a" -> x_] :> x + 10, 
  KeyValuePattern["b" -> x_] :> x + 100}
```

> 11

And this throws a `ReplaceAll` error:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> /. 
 KeyValuePattern[{("a" -> x_) :> x + 10, ("b" -> x_) :> x + 100}]
```

> "!({KeyValuePattern[{((\"a\" -> x_)) :> x + 10, ((\"b\" -> x_))
>   :> x + 100}]}) is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid
>   dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing"

The desired behavior is what you'd expect from List:

```
{"a" -> 1,"b" -> 2} /. {("a" -> x_) :> x + 10, ("b" -> x_) :> x + 100}
```

> {11,102}

**EDIT**

Note the `List` version will match individual key-value pairs, eg:

```
{"a" -> 1} /. {("a" -> x_) :> x + 10, ("b" -> x_) :> x + 100}
```

> {11}

The solution should match and replace individual key-value pairs in the `Association`.

(Want to avoid `Normal` to list as this is a minimal example but in practice the values are nested `Associations`.)

Comment: @kglr, that doesn't work for me in v12 (I copy-pasted your code verbatim), I get the input back in the output unmatched.

Comment: @kglr, please see my updated comment - it doesn't work at all.

Comment: sorry, miscopied; should be `<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> /.  KeyValuePattern[{"a" -> x_, "b" ->y_}]:>{ x+10, y + 100}`

Comment: @kglr, no that doesn't work as intended, Since it won't match individual key-values, eg `<|"a" -> 1|> /. 
 KeyValuePattern[{"a" -> x_, "b" -> y_}] :> {x + 10, y + 100}` - will update my Q to make that explicit.

Comment: If your first example had worked, it would have returned the malformed `Association[ 11, 102]`.  If you had just the two replacement rules that you have, what would you want returned from `<|"a" ->3, "c" -> 4|>` or `<|"a"-> <|"b"->2|>, "b" ->7|>`?

Answer (score 2):

`ReplaceList` seems to work:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> // 
 ReplaceList[{KeyValuePattern["a" -> x_] :> x + 10, 
   KeyValuePattern["b" -> x_] :> x + 100}]
```

> {11, 102}

```
<|"a" -> 1|> // 
 ReplaceList[{KeyValuePattern["a" -> x_] :> x + 10, 
   KeyValuePattern["b" -> x_] :> x + 100}]
```

> {11}

And it also seems to almost* handle a workaround to another KeyValuePattern issue - by design it only matches the first key, even though there may be multiple keys that match a given key-pattern:

```
<|{"a", "x"} -> 1, {"b", "y"} -> 2, {"a", "z"} -> 3|> // 
 ReplaceList[{KeyValuePattern[{"a", k_} -> x_] :> {k, x + 10}, 
   KeyValuePattern[{"b", k_} -> x_] :> {k, x + 100}}]
```

> {{"x", 11}, {"z", 13}, {"y", 102}}

*almost = does not preserve input key order.

I've asked support to add an `Option` MatchAllKeys` since typically that's more useful that matching only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`KeyValueMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValueMap) instead:

```
KeyValueMap[#1 /. {"a" :> #2 + 10, "b" :> #2 + 100}&] @ <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
```

> {11, 102}

or:

```
KeyValueMap[
    Function[{key, value}, key->value /. {("a"->x_) -> x+10, ("b"->x_) -> x+100}]
] @ <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>
```

> {11, 102}

Second example:

```
assoc = <|{"a","x"}->1,{"b","y"}->2,{"a","z"}->3|>;
KeyValueMap[#1 /. {{"a",k_} :> {k,#2+10}, {"b", k_} :> {k,#2+100}}&] @ assoc
```

> {{"x", 11}, {"y", 102}, {"z", 13}}

Comment: thanks but in practice as mentioned in the Q, the values are actually associations so want to avoid `Slot/Part` as vestiges of the 20th century.